# Eclipse plugin: Add new menu into SVN > Team pop-up menu

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, plugins

I am developing an Eclipse plugin. I want to add new additional menu into existed menu of SVN plugin of eclipse (appear when right click on project name and choose "Team" menu from the pop-up)

Here my plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?eclipse version="3.4"?>
      <plugin>
          <extension point = "org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
             <objectContribution id="com.company.svn.checkout" objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
        <menu
            id="com.company.svn.checkout.CheckoutProjectStructure"
            label="Team"
            path="additions">
            <separator name="group1"/>
        </menu>
        <action id="com.company.svn.checkout.submenu.CheckoutProjectStructure"
           label="Update Project Data"
           icon="icons/renameProject.png"
           menubarPath="com.company.svn.checkout.CheckoutProjectStructure/group1" 
           helpContextId="com.company.svn.checkout.CheckoutProjectStructure"
           class="com.company.svn.checkout.UpdateProjectDataDelegate"
           enablesFor="1">
        </action>
     </objectContribution>
</extension>
```

But it just add new separate menu and there are two menus "Team" in the pop up. How to "merge" them into 1 menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the existing `team.main` menu in the `menubarPath`

For example one of the SVN actions:

```xml
<objectContribution
    adaptable="true"
    objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"
    id="org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.ConnectedProjectContributions">

    <action
        label="%DisconnectAction.label"
        helpContextId="org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.team_disconnect_action_context"
        class="org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.action.local.management.DisconnectAction"
        tooltip="%DisconnectAction.tooltip"
        menubarPath="team.main/projectGroup"
        definitionId="org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.command.DisconnectCommand"
        id="org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.action.local.management.DisconnectAction">
    </action>

</objectContribution>
```